# Why flashing a ROM causes the IMEI to go 'generic' -sometimes (even if it's a stock ROM)?

Tags: rom-flashing, odin, stock-rom, imei

the story I'll tell you will help you with the answer.

One year ago, my dad's phone (Galaxy Note 3) had many issues (because the phone was rooted and something messed up the system files). I've tried to flash a stock ROM using Odin (I was sure that the downloaded ROM matched the model and the PDA/AP). After flashing the ROM, everything was working fine except the mobile-related functions. The IMEI has been changed to a generic one (it started with 0049*********) and so the phone wasn't able to connect to the mobile network (no calls, no sms, no mobile internet).

That was even weirdier, because the first time I flashed that phone (to downgrade to Android KitKat), the IMEI remained untouched, but the last time the IMEI was altered.

So, why does flashing a ROM **sometimes** reset the IMEI?

Comment: This happens when you flash a file from a different region that the device was made for.

Comment: So, if the ROM matches the **exact** region, does IMEI remain untouched?

Comment: Assuming there is no hardware failure, yes. Flashing correct firmware would restore your original IMEI. Otherwise you'll need to "repair" manually

Comment: `Flashing correct firmware` didn't work, I had to go to a repair service. The next time how can I ensure the firmware is correct?

Comment: You need to know the correct region then download the firmware accordingly. The thing is you need the same radio